# Technique on UV seaming bevels?

Tags: texturing, uv, edges, seams

I'm looking for expert advise on how to get a good seam on this object.

I have a vintage television here that is ready for texturing. I'm at a loss for how to add UV seams to the bevelled corners. Later, throughout seaming, I considered running a loop cut in the middle of the bevel and seaming it, but I believe it is inefficient.

Do you have any expert advice?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, why do you think it is inefficient? It depends on how you want the texture to be projected, the way you do it works, as L0lock's way

Comment: I think it is inefficient because I would have to add more polygon count and had to like manually place them because you can't just run multiple loops through triangles and you'd have to like add a vertex at them and join them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default cube as an example, I would just use seams on 2 of the 3 edges of each bevel's triangles like so:

[image]

I think of it as the little tabs of a paper template to put the glue on.